# How to check in bash if a file is currently in use from a sshfs mount

Tags: bash, debian, sshfs

I have a home server being used as a nas. The storage is mounted on my desktop via sshfs. What I would like to accomplish is to write a bash script which unmounts the nas and powers it down at a certain time, but only if there is no file opened from the sshfs mount or music being played from the sshfs mount. I know how to use cron or use date, check if there is an sshfs mount ( e.g. ss | grep -i ssh ), unmount sshfs and poweroff the nas remotely.

How do I check if a file is currently in use on the sshfs mount?

Comment: Why use sshfs on your home LAN when you could use NFS (linux clients) and/or Samba (MS Windows clients)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is called "fuser".  Check out its man page.

Comment: fuser -m /path/to/filesystem shows processes that use the file system, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use `lsof`

```
lsof /mount/point
```

will list open files in the given location with info on commands, PIDs and users. Exit status 0 on finds, 1 on no finds (or any errors).

Comment: Thank you usefull as well!